# why v2=6 and v3=6?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

In above circuit I have seen in a book reference [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlzT0.jpg) is i=0, v1=0 , v2=6v , and v3=6v.
I can see how they find i=0 also v1=0 but I hvae hard time to see how they find v2 and v3

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlzT0.jpg): Design with operational amplifers and analog integrated circuits by Sergio Franco

Comment: Because the voltage source adds 6V to whatever is on its -ve terminal (V1).

Answer (score 2):

Since there is nothing connected at the v3 node, there is no current through any of the resistors.

Therefore, by Ohm's Law, there is no voltage drop across any of the resistors.

Therefore v1 is at 0 V, and v2 and v3 are at +6 V.

Comment: If I consider the same reason why I do not say v1=-6

Comment: @Caro, v1 is connected to ground (0 V by definition) through a resistor with 0 current through it and therefore 0 V across it.